# Use current post as option in advanced custom fields select

Tags: custom-post-type, advanced-custom-fields

I've got a custom post type 'reizen'.
I'd like to use the current post from this post type as an option in an acf select.
How to get this working?

The class of the select is .iphorm_2_1

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using the select field you can use the 'post object' field and filter it so that you can only choose from the 'reizen' post type. On the edit screen this will produce a dropdown of posts within 'reizen'.